# correct logic to update location to server via volley for multiple orders in delivery boy app

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am trying to build an android app for delivery boy.Where he starts the order by clicking a button which updates order status in database.Now,I want to update his location every time his location is changes which can be done by onLocationChange, but i am stuck as there are multiple orders which he can have.Also if this should be done in a service or in the activity itself.
Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

It's a long-running background task, so need to be done in service. 
Also, there is nothing to do with multiple orders. Whats so ever order he is delivering, he would be having a unique location to be updated to the server.

So there would be a service which is updating the location to the server.